# Solving this inequality: $e^x \geq x^e$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation, eulers-number-e

Show that $e^x  \geq  x^e$ for $ 0 \lt x \lt \infty $.

I tried to apply the normal logarithm here, which yields $x \geq e\times \ln(x)$
Still, I am kind of stuck here, anyone mind giving me a hand?

Comment: See also: 
[Why $e^x$ is always greater than $x^e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619911) and
[Prove the inequality $e^x \geq x^e$ for $x > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1344288).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider the function $f(x) = e^x - x^e$ and find its minimum over positive $x$.
If you do it correctly (e.g. solve $f'(x) = 0$, etc) you will find that it is non-negative. Hence, the claim will follow.

**UPDATE**

Easier to take logs: $e^x \ge x^e$ iff $x \ge e \ln x$, and now look at $f(x) = x - e \ln x$, which should be elementary

Comment: f′(x) = $e^x$ - e*$x^{e-1}$ which would give $e^x$ - e*$x^{e-1}$ = 0. The equation becomes  e($e^{x-1}$ - $x^{e-1}$) = 0

Which would mean that 
$e^{x-1}$ - $x^{e-1}$ = 0

How do I find the root here? I mean, I can see the roots are x = 1 and x = e, but I can't seem to solve it.

I understand that once I solve it and prove that the local minimum point for the function is positive, then the original claim is true.

Comment: @MikhaelM please see update, taking logs making things very basic

Comment: Yup, thank you, I missed that somehow. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $e^{x/e}$ is convex and $y=x$ is its tangent at $x=e$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=x-eln(x)$. $f'$ exists,
$$
f'(x) = 1-\frac{e}{x}.
$$
That function has a root,  Which are easily found: $x=e$. Now, $f'$ is negative in $e-h$ and positive in $e+h$ with appropriate $h$, so that critical point is a minimum. When plugged into the original function, we have $0$, so the argument is indeed true.