# Prove the inequality $e^x \geq x^e$ for $x > 0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Prove that $e^x \ge x^e$ for $x \gt 0$

I applied the natural logarithm to simplify the function and I get $$\frac{x}{\ln x}\ge e$$

How to solve these types of problems?

Comment: How did you get this equality from the starting inequality ?

Comment: One ought to mention in any proof that the equivalence of $e^x \geq x^e$ and the inequality $x \geq e \log x$ are equivalent because $\log$ is an increasing function---this argument does not hold if we replace it with a general function.

Comment: Ugh, formatting issues, I didn't get an equality at the end. It's still an inequality, I edited now.

Comment: @MikhaelM Note you cannot divide by $\log x$ unless you are sure it is positive, i.e. $x > 1$.  For $x \in (0, 1)$, that division will reverse the inequality.

Comment: See also: [Why $e^x$ is always greater than $x^e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619911) and
[Prove the inequality $e^x \geq x^e$ for $x > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1344288).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are alsmot there.

Study the function $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$

Then $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}(1-\ln x)$

$f'(x)>0$ for $x<e$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $x>e$

But $f(e)=\dfrac 1e$...

Comment: Oh I get it, so the function x/lnx has a minimum in e, so that f(e) = e is the minimal value that the function can take. Thus, the function x/lnx has to be greater or equal to e. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

$e^{x/e}$ is convex and its tangent at $x=e$ is $y = x$, hence $e^{x/e} \ge x$

Answer (score 1):

$x \geq e\ln x \iff x - e\ln x \geq 0$. $f(x) = x - e\ln x \to f'(x) = 1-\dfrac{e}{x}=\dfrac{x-e}{x}\geq 0 \iff x \geq e$. Thus if $x \geq e, f(x) \geq f(e) = 0 \to x \geq e\ln x \to e^x \geq x^e$, and if $x \leq 0, f(x) \geq f(e) = 0 \to e^x \geq x^e$.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the function 
\begin{equation}f(x)=e^x-x^e
\end{equation}
and show that $f'(x)$ is zero at $x=1,e$ and go forth in terms of the minima of $f(x)$. With this, however, you will also have to show that $f(x)$ doesn't achieve a minimum at $\pm\infty$...