# How to prove: $e^x \ge x^e$ for $x>0$

Tags: inequality

I stumbled upon this problem and can't find a solution.
I tried taking the derivative of this function $e^x - x^e$ and got this function:
$e(e^{x-1} - x^{e-1})$ and I can't prove it is positive or equal to zero because it's almost my original problem. 
If i could prove the derivative was always positive then i could say that the function is strictly increasing and because the limit as $x \to 0^{+}$, of the function is positive then it must mean that $e^x \ge x^e$.

Comment: Hint:  take logs of both sides to see that this is the same as $x≥e\ln \,x$.  Now, where does the function $f(x)=x-e\ln \,x$ have a minimum?

Comment: Hint: $x^e = \exp(e \cdot \log(x))$

Comment: Duplicate: [Why $e^x$ is always greater than $x^e$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619911/201168)

Comment: The minimum value will be $f(e)$ which is 0 so $f(x) >= 0$, $x>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better to consider the function
$$
f(x)=x-e\log x
$$
(natural logarithm). The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{e}{x}=\frac{x-e}{x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

From $\log(x) \leq x-1$ for all $x>0$ it follows that $$\log(e x) = 1 + \log(x) \leq x.$$ Substitute $x \leftarrow e^{-1}x$ to get $$\log(x) \leq e^{-1}x$$ and this is an equivalent form of your inequality.