# Prove that for every $a \in ℝ$ and for every $x>0$ the inequality $x^{-a}+a · e · \ln(x) \geq 0$ holds

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

I have tried some techniques to solve the following problem but I was unable to solve it:

> "Prove that for every $a \in ℝ$ and for every $x>0$ the inequality $x^{-a}+a · e · \ln(x) \geq 0$ holds".

I tried to take the derivative and see if it is always positive, I tried a direct approach manipulating the expression, I also tried to divide it in cases, but I always find troubles.
I would appreciate any help or hint you could give me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can transform the inequality:
\begin{align}
x^{-a}+ae\ln(x) &\geq 0\\
\implies \ln\left(e^{x^{-a}}\right) + \ln\left(x^{ae}\right) &\geq 0\\
\implies \ln\left(e^{x^{-a}}x^{ae}\right) \geq 0\\
\implies e^{x^{-a}}x^{ae} \geq 1\\
\implies e^{x^{-a}} \geq x^{-ae}.
\end{align}

Now, setting $y = x^{-a}$, we note that $x>0, a\in \mathbb{R} \implies y > 0$, so we wish to prove that for all $y>0$ we have$$e^{y} \geq y^{e},$$ which is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619911/why-ex-is-always-greater-than-xe).

Answer (score 4):

$$
x^{-a}+ae \ln(x) = e^{-a \ln(x)} + ae \ln(x)
$$
so that, with the substitution $u = -a \ln (x)$, this is equivalent to showing that
$$
 e^u \ge eu
$$
for all $u \in \Bbb R$, and that is true because $f(u) = e^u$ is convex:
$$
 e^u = f(u) \ge f(1) + (u-1)f'(1) = e + (u-1)e = eu \, .
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f_x(a):=e^{-a\ln x}+ae\ln x.$$
For $x=1$, it is clear that $f_1(a)=1\geq0$. Now let $x\neq0$, then
$$f'_x(a)=-e^{-a\ln x}\ln x  +e\ln x\overset{!}{=}0\Leftrightarrow a=-1/\ln x.$$
Now you just have to think about, why this is a minimum point and thus the minimum of the function is $$f_x(-1/\ln x)=0.$$

Comment: Nice proof (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Define the function $f:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(x)=x^{-a}+ae\ln(x)$$
Show that $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to0^+$ and $x\to +\infty$. Conclude that $f$ attains its global minimum. Use its derivative to find where it is. You will see that $f(x)=0$ at that point, so we get $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in (0,+\infty)$