# is it $e^\pi<\pi^e$ or $\pi^e<e^\pi$? and how do we prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, pi

is it $e^\pi<\pi^e$ or $\pi^e<e^\pi$? it's an interesting question that just came to my mind, well of course I used the calculator to get the answer, However I need to like prove it and I don't know where I should start from.

Comment: Hint: show that $f(x) = \ln(x)/x$ is decreasing on $x>e$.

Comment: $\pi^e<e^{\pi}$, and this has definitely been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7892/568204).

Answer (score 0):

the relationship is not specific to $\pi$, see the following question: [Why $e^x$ is always greater than $x^e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619911/why-ex-is-always-greater-than-xe)